# Using wp_mail to send attachment from a file stream content

Tags: attachments, wp-mail, curl

I am using `wp_mail` to send mail with attachment. The attachment is not stored anywhere. The attachment contents are fetched via`curl` request.

This is what I wrote. This function below (`send_stream_attachments`) is working but sending jumbled texts without any attachments. The file contents are seemed to be printed in the email body.

```php
send_stream_attachments($user_email, $subject, ['file' => $invoice_id.'.pdf', 'content' => $pdf], 'application/pdf');

function send_stream_attachments($mail_to, $mail_subj, $stream= ['file'=> '', 'content'=>''], $ftype= 'application/octet-stream', $tmpl= 'default')
{
    //$stream['file'] (Attachment file name)
    //$stream['content'] (Attachment content fetched via curl)
    // I have checked the values and all are OK

    $stat= ['stat' => 0, 'log' => ''];

    $eol = PHP_EOL;
    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; charset=UTF-8; boundary=\"".$uid."\"".$eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol;

    $attachment_content = chunk_split($stream['content']);

    $email_body = "--".$uid.$eol;
    $email_body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8; boundary=\"".$uid."\"";
    
    $email_body.= '<p>Hi,</p><p>This is your file.</p>';

    $email_body .= "--".$uid.$eol;
    $email_body .= "Content-Type: '.$ftype'; name=\"".$stream['file']."\"".$eol;
    $email_body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
    $email_body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol;
    $email_body .= $attachment_content.$eol;
    $email_body .= "--".$uid."--";

    $stat['stat']= wp_mail($mail_to, $mail_subj, $email_body, $headers);

    return $stat;
}
```

PS: I know I can save the content and unlink the file after the email is sent will work. But is there any method to override this saving?

Thank you so much for reading this far and also for your thoughts on the issue.

Comment: attachments have to be passed as an array after the headers when using `wp_mail`, it's written to expect the array to contain file paths. If there's a way to record your files as paths then it's possible, otherwise you'll need to write the stream somewhere then remove the files after they've been mailed if you want to use `wp_mail` directly. It's possible filters could be used to interface with PHPMailer and the internals but I'm not sure about that. Appending new HTTP headers to the email body won't work

Comment: Thank you @TomJNowell. I can definitely save the file and unlink it after `wp_mail`. But just seeking if there is any method without saving the file.